"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()" error on Angular code while using login and signup functions
I am currently building this angular app, but for some reason the fetch posts for login and signup give me this error. First time when I ran the app, it went smoothly, after I loaded it a second time it started showing this error
auth.component.ts: (login page typescript)
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {
  AuthResponseData,
  AuthService,
} from '../../services/auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth',
  templateUrl: './auth.component.html',
})
export class AuthComponent {
  isLoginMode = true;
  isLoading = false;
  error: string = null;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  onSwitchMode() {
    this.isLoginMode = !this.isLoginMode;
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (!form.valid) {
      return;
    }
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;

    let authObs: Observable<AuthResponseData>;

    this.isLoading = true;

    if (this.isLoginMode) {
      authObs = this.authService.login(email, password);
    } else {
      authObs = this.authService.signup(email, password);
    }

    authObs.subscribe(
      (resData) => {
        console.log(resData);
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/recipes']);
      },
      (errorMessage) => {
        console.log(errorMessage);
        this.error = errorMessage;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    );

    form.reset();
  }
}

And my auth.service.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

import { User } from '../../models/user.model';

export interface AuthResponseData {
  kind: string;
  idToken: string;
  email: string;
  refreshToken: string;
  expiresIn: string;
  localId: string;
  registered?: boolean;
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
  private tokenExpirationTimer: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  signup(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http
      .post<AuthResponseData>(
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=****',
        {
          email: email,
          password: password,
          returnSecureToken: true,
        }
      )
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError),
        tap((resData) => {
          this.handleAuthentication(
            resData.email,
            resData.localId,
            resData.idToken,
            +resData.expiresIn
          );
        })
      );
  }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http
      .post<AuthResponseData>(
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=****',
        {
          email: email,
          password: password,
          returnSecureToken: true,
        }
      )
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError),
        tap((resData) => {
          this.handleAuthentication(
            resData.email,
            resData.localId,
            resData.idToken,
            +resData.expiresIn
          );
        })
      );
  }

  autoLogin() {
    const userData: {
      email: string;
      id: string;
      _token: string;
      _tokenExpirationDate: string;
    } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
    if (!userData) {
      return;
    }

    const loadedUser = new User(
      userData.email,
      userData.id,
      userData._token,
      new Date(userData._tokenExpirationDate)
    );

    if (loadedUser.token) {
      this.user.next(loadedUser);
      const expirationDuration =
        new Date(userData._tokenExpirationDate).getTime() -
        new Date().getTime();
      this.autoLogout(expirationDuration);
    }
  }

  logout() {
    this.user.next(null);
    this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
    localStorage.removeItem('userData');
    if (this.tokenExpirationTimer) {
      clearTimeout(this.tokenExpirationTimer);
    }
    this.tokenExpirationTimer = null;
  }

  autoLogout(expirationDuration: number) {
    this.tokenExpirationTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.logout();
    }, expirationDuration);
  }

  private handleAuthentication(
    email: string,
    userId: string,
    token: string,
    expiresIn: number
  ) {
    const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + expiresIn * 1000);
    const user = new User(email, userId, token, expirationDate);
    this.user.next(user);
    this.autoLogout(expiresIn * 1000);
    localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(user));
  }

  private handleError(errorRes: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = 'An unknown error occurred!';
    if (!errorRes.error || !errorRes.error.error) {
      return throwError(errorMessage);
    }
    switch (errorRes.error.error.message) {
      case 'EMAIL_EXISTS':
        errorMessage = 'This email exists already';
        break;
      case 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND':
        errorMessage = 'This email does not exist.';
        break;
      case 'INVALID_PASSWORD':
        errorMessage = 'This password is not correct.';
        break;
    }
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}

I have double checked API key, I have checked the authorized domains on firebase. None of it works

The 400 error indicates a bad request, meaning there's an issue with the data being sent to the server. Here's how you can debug and resolve it:
1.Check the API Key and see if is same as in your Firebase console under Project Settings > General > Web API Key
2.Verify that the email, password, and returnSecureToken fields are being sent correctly. Log the payload before making the HTTP request: console.log({ email, password, returnSecureToken: true });
3.Check if your Firebase project is set up to allow email/password authentication. Go to Firebase Console > Authentication > Sign-in Method. Enable “Email/Password”.
4.Inspect Server’s response by logging it to console : catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {

console.error('Error response:', error);
return this.handleError(error);
})

5.Use browser dev tools (Network tab) to inspect the actual request being sent. Ensure the request body matches Firebase’s Api requirements.
6.Use Curl command and check if it is also returning the same response. curl -X POST 
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=YOUR_API_KEY 
-d '{
"email": "your_email@example.com",
"password": "your_password"
}'

No I have not used any AI tools to generate this answer. Though I have used grammarly to correct the grammar in my answer. Thanks for understanding.
